# How to stop Wit.ai from classifying 4 digit numbers as datetime entities?

Tags: datetime, wit.ai

In my wit.ai application, I sometimes have 4 digits numbers that are used in a way like citations: `1029 B 4930`, and I need to label them as such.

Instead wit.ai labels them as "datetime" and I can see why.

I also do need recognition of real datetimes in my application at times, which might make this a more difficult issue.

Is there a way to prevent wit.ai from labelling 4 digit numbers as dates in certain contexts?

Comment: I don't think so, but you can handle it on server side with a regex.